# .txt to separate worksheets

Tags: vba, text, import

I'm trying to use the following code to import multiple .txt into separate separate sheets in a workbook. In all of the worksheets it fails to space delimit the last row and from worksheet 2 onward it also fails to copy the first line of the .txt file. All the txt. files are the exactly the same format. Any help appreciated.

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()
    Dim FilesToOpen
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar:="|"

        Dim lastrowA As Long
        Dim lastrowB As Long
        Dim sheetname As String

        With ActiveSheet
            lastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lastrowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
            Range("a1").EntireColumn.Insert
            Range("a1").Value = sheetname
            Range("a2" & ":a" & lastrowB).Value = Range("a1")
            Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
        End With


    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
        xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False

        End With


    With ActiveSheet
            lastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            lastrowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
            Range("a1").Value = sheetname
            Range("a2" & ":a" & lastrowB).Value = Range("a1")
            Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
    End With

        x = x + 1

    Wend

ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler



End Sub
```

Comment: Can you make [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you would probably find the mistake yourself. However, by your description for the first row, I guess the problem is here:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Range("a1").EntireColumn.Insert
    Range("a1").Value = sheetname
    Range("a2" & ":a" & lastrowB).Value = Range("a1")
    Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
End With
```

You need to declare the ranges like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    lastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowB = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    .Range("a1").EntireColumn.Insert
    .Range("a1").Value = sheetname
    .Range("a2" & ":a" & lastrowB).Value = .Range("a1")
    .Range("a1").EntireRow.Insert
End With
```

See the dots, they make the difference. If the code is located in a worksheet, then the ranges take the worksheet they are located to, as a Parent worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Vityata. Missed the range problem (its sorted now, thanks), but I still can't work out why the last row is not delimited

Comment: @Ian - is the last row everywhere not delimited? I guess it should be ok, on the `ActiveSheet`. In general, read this and rewrite the whole code avoiding `ActiveSheet`, it may work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: The activesheet sections are just some labels I need but I'll rewrite and remove them. Even without the activesheet section none of the last rows on any sheets are delimited

Comment: @Ian you should mark it as answer if Vityata gave u a solution.

Comment: @george86 Still trying to sort out the last line not being delimited otherwise I would have

Comment: @Ian - put a screenshot, it would be easier.

Comment: @Ian I am sorry, I saw your comment "Thanks Vityata. Missed the range problem (its sorted now, thanks), " &  thought it is solved...Didn't read that completely